# Dart commands not running in windows 11. What do I do to make it run?

Tags: dart

Dart command is not running on
Windows 11, what should I do?

`Dart is not a recognized internal or external command, batch file`

Answer (score 0):

Add the path of the bin folder of the Dart SDK to the PATH environment variable of the current user (Windows key+S, type environment).

Comment: Please  I've added it to the environmental variables. It's works when I open a dart project in vscode, but when I run commands in cmd. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This happens if dart is not in your `PATH`.

1. Open `cmd`
2. Enter the command `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`
3. Double click on `Path` and add the location of the dart binaries you installed at the bottom of the list.
4. Close all terminal windows and reopen.